# Markdown file path complete in VSCode

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, markdown

Is there any path-autocompletion extension for **Markdown** in VSCode?

I tried [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) but this seems to be effective only when using (double) quotation.

I want to use autocompletion when insert images stored in local directory, e.g.:

```
![](./img/local-img-file.png)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make that happen by using this extension on VS Code.

[Relative Path extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath)

Juste type `ctrl` (or `cmd` on mac) + `shift` + `H` and type your file name.

Answer (score 2):

It should be built-in to vscode soon, hopefully v1.64.

New setting:   `markdown.suggest.paths.enabled`  default is `true`

- from Commit: [Add basic markdown link completions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/a4e529c759fae0c15bb4bb8817ac3e7428793164)

> Only normal links for now. Will add reference links later. Should
> support the forms:
>
> - `[](dir/file.md)`
> - `[](./dir/file.md)`
> - `[](/root-dir/file.md)`
> - `[](#header)`
> - `[](./dir/file.md#header)`
>
> The paths suggestions work similarly to path IntelliSense in CSS and
> HTML files. Paths starting with / are resolved relative to the current
> workspace, while paths staring with ./ or without any prefix are
> resolved relative to the current file. Path suggestions are
> automatically shown when you type / or can be manually invoked by
> using kb(`editor.action.triggerSuggest`).
>
> Path IntelliSense can also help you link to headers within the current
> file or within another Markdown file. Start the path with # to see
> completions for all the headers in the file (depending on your
> settings, you may need to use kb(`editor.action.triggerSuggest`) to see
> these)

-from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#markdown-path-intellisense

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling upon this answer, the [Markdown All in One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) extension is able to perform this sort of autocomplete.